# Trying to define method in interface. Says "expected a type"

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Asset.h"

@interface Person : NSObject{
    int pin;
    NSMutableArray* assets;
}

@property int pin;
-(void) addAsset: (Asset*) iasset; //producing error
@end
```

Trying to code the interface of a "Person" class that contains an array of "assets". 
The line

```
 -(void) addAsset: (Asset*) iasset;
```

produces an error. XCode says, "Expected a type". Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I can provide whatever other code is needed.

Asset.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface Asset : NSObject{
    NSString* label;
    int value;
    Person* holder; 
}
@property int value;
-(void) setHolder: (Person*)iholder;
-(void) setLabel: (NSString*)iname;
@end
```

Comment: You should show us the contents of Asset.h.

Comment: What does Asset.h look like?  There needs to be a class definition in it

Comment: You've got yourself a case of the Header Import Cycles.  Notice how `Asset` imports `Person` and `Person` imports `Asset`?

Comment: How do i fix this? Don't both require eachother?

Answer (score 4):

You have a circular dependency in your header files.  You can fix it by removing `#import "Person.h"` in `Asset.h` and replacing it with `@class Person;`.  This change will tell the compiler about the existence of the `Person` class without requiring the header to be imported.

Likewise, you could instead replace `#import "Asset.h"` in `Person.h` with `@class Asset;`.

You'll still want to include the correct headers from your implementation files.

Comment: Thank you sir! Could you explain to me how I go about choosing between @class and #import? My book brought it up but did very little explaining.

Comment: Use `#import` when possible I guess?  It makes your life (marginally) easier.  If you have to break a cycle, pick a spot and use `@class`.  That's it.

Comment: @Kevin's advice seems reasonable to me.  Let's go with that.

Comment: @ByronShilly - In general, if you're only referencing the class as a pointer, you can use `@class`.  (You do then need to remember to `#import` the Asset.h file in the Person.m file, though.)  I tend to use `@class` much of the time, just on the theory that it compiles a little faster.